# How to depoly an Ubuntu touch QML application for other GNU/Linux distributions?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml

My situation:

- I have created an Ubuntu touch application using Ubuntu SDK, in QML & C++.
- The application uses Ubuntu's UI Toolkit (Ubuntu.Components 0.1) located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu`
- I want the application to run in other GNU/Linux distributions as well.

How to deploy this application along with Ubuntu QML Components, so that it runs on other GNU/Linux distributions as well?

(Lets assume non-Ubuntu Linux distribution has QT5 installed.)

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't worked with Ubuntu Touch in a couple years, BUT... 1. If the target distro is Ubuntu-based you might be able to get away with requiring the Ubuntu Touch package(s) in your .deb.  2. Otherwise, you'll have to copy the necessary QML components you need into your own project, and follow Canonical's license requirements (legal questions are generally off topic here.)

Comment: Thanks. Option 2 is what I want to do, but I don't know how :(